# If $\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$, then find $y_n$ ($n^{th} $differention of the equation).

Tags: calculus, differential

The answer:

$$\frac{2(-1)^n \cdot n!}{\sqrt{3}r^{n+1}}\sin(n+1)\theta,$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$ and $\theta=\cot^{-1}\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

How I have tried:

$$y=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$y=\frac{1}{(x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{4})}$$

$$y=\frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{3}{4}}$$

$$y=\frac{4}{(2x+1)^2-3}$$

**I don't know how to proceed further, someone please help.**

Comment: Why don't you use mathematical induction to prove it?

Comment: i did"nt know any other way to do it..

Comment: Wait, are you supposed to prove that the nth derivative is that expression or you need to derive that expression without knowing what it is?

Comment: u need to find the $n^{th}$ derivative for expression $\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Let $x^2+x+1=(x-a)(x-b)$

So, we can write $\displaystyle a,b=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3i}2$

$$\implies\frac1{x^2+x+1}=\frac1{a-b}\left(\frac1{x-b}-\frac1{x-a}\right)$$

Now from [this](http://www.vitutor.com/calculus/derivatives/nth_derivative.html) and many others,  $$\frac{d^n(1/(x-a))}{dx}=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{(x-a)^{n+1}}$$

For $\displaystyle x-a=x-\left(\dfrac12+i\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\right)$  set $x-\dfrac12=r\cos\phi,$  and $-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=r\sin\phi$

and apply de Movire Theorem

Comment: sir,how is$ x^2+x+1=(x-a)(x-b)$??? n how is$\displaystyle a=e^{\frac{e^{i\pi}}3},b=e^{\frac{e^{2i\pi}}3}$??

Comment: @Nikhil01, What are the roots of $x^2+x=1=0?$

Comment: How is $e^{\frac{e^{i \pi}}{3}}=1/2+i(\sqrt{3} / 2)$?

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi, Please find the edited answer

Comment: @lab bhatttacharjee thank you.u always come to my rescue :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. I was about to answer the same ! In year 2010, I published a paper about the zeros of $$\frac{d^nP}{dV^n}$$ where $$P=\frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{V^2+ubV+wb^2}$$ and doing what you proposed makes the $n^{th}$ derivative immediate, analytic and nice (I used up to $n=10^6) ! Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Nice to hear that

Comment: @lab bhattachajee  how did you take out $\frac{1}{(a-b)}$out of the equation $(\frac1{x-b}-\frac1{x-a})$?? on finding the roots you only get  $(\frac1{x-b}-\frac1{x-a})$ right?? how did u get $\frac{1}{(a-b)}$??

Comment: @Nikhil01, $$\frac{a-b}{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{(x-b)-(x-a)}{(x-a)(x-b)}=?$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee got it thank you!!